# How generate a Sequence from String Request?

Tags: java, android

I try of build an app with Google maps and JSON, but i need generate a sequence from a Stringrequest.

I intent the below way, but it get result null

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urltime, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.e("Response: ", response);

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
            String getObject = jObj.getString("saagPos");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                coorWay = coorWay + "|" + jsonObject.getString(LAT2) + "," + jsonObject.getString(LNG2);

                if (bangaloreRoute == null) {
                    bangaloreRoute = new ArrayList<>();
                } else {
                    bangaloreRoute.clear();
                }

                bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT2)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG2))));

                // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {…
    }
}
```

And I need get the below sequence, repeating `bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(...`, for each result, in this way for example:

```
bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(12.922294704121231, 77.61939525604248));
bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(12.924637088068884, 77.6180648803711));
bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(12.925557304321782, 77.6200819015503));
bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(12.927104933097784, 77.62081146240234));
bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(12.928234277770715, 77.62111186981201));
bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(12.92990737159723, 77.6218843460083));
bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(12.9337554448302, 77.62342929840088));
```

How could that sequence generate, to build a route from my StringRequest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing where `bangaloreRoute` initially gets defined, but it looks like you have a bug in your code here:

```
            if (bangaloreRoute == null) {
                bangaloreRoute = new ArrayList<>();
            } else {
                bangaloreRoute.clear();
            }
```

The above is part of your main loop.  This effectively is saying "The first time, if `bangaloreRoute` is null, create a new `ArrayList`"  That's fine.  But then the `else` is *always* clearing out the bangaloreRoute ArrayList, *regardless of what was in it already*.

So, every single time your loop goes through this code, it's clearing what the *previous* loop iteration added.  In the end, you're going to end up with a single `LatLng` element, just the last one that was added.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you are clearing the arraylist at every cycle of the for loop and inserting new data. Hence there is no data in your **bangaloreroute** arraylist.

Try the below modification and replace it with this:

```
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urltime, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        if(bangaloreRoute ==null)
             bangaloreRoute =new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response: ", response);

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String getObject = jObj.getString("saagPos");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    coorWay = coorWay + "|" + jsonObject.getString(LAT2) + "," + jsonObject.getString(LNG2);

                    bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT2)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG2))));

                    // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this should resolve your issue..

Comment: Hi, show me error unexpected token in `if(bangaloreRoute ==null)`

Comment: Okay, write the below lines in your onCreate():

`if(bangaloreRoute ==null)
             bangaloreRoute =new ArrayList<>();`

And remove it from the above code.

Comment: My error  continue is in create the list from StringRequest, when i put list manually, work, but when i try build list this: `bangaloreRoute.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT2)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG2))));` , not load nothing

Comment: I think you are not getting any data LAT2 and LNG2.. may be you need to check that..